# Unity3d isLocalPlayer issue

Tags: c#, game-engine, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with isLocalPlayer bool in Unity. I have simple moving script, where I want to move a player if isLocalPlayer. But isLocalPlayer always returns false. Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerRotating : NetworkBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(isLocalPlayer)
        {
            var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
            var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

            transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
            transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
        }
    }
}
```

My player prefab inspector:

[image: My player prefab inspector]

Comment: Can you show where `isLocalPlayer` is defined?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I have not defined isLocalPlayer anywhere.

Comment: That would be why it is always `false`

Comment: I don't have to define it anywhere, it is predefined by unity

Comment: Is there a `start.server()` or `start.host()` in any of your scripts?

Comment: And also make sure that - network manager game object > spawn information > auto create player is checked

Comment: @Minzkraut there is: Network.InitializeServer(20, 25001, !Network.HavePublicAddress());

Comment: @xtrontross Ok in that case it's not  what I meant... what about the auto create player thing?

Comment: Hm. Are you sure it's always false? Add this to Update() -> "Debug.Log("isLocalPlayer == " + isLocalPlayer);", as the first line of code, before your 'if'.

Comment: Try adding this method `void OnStartLocalPlayer(){Debug.Log("Hello");}` . Is this printing?? isLocalPlayer won't be set if Localplayer is not setup